# Connect React App served on dockerized Nginx to Express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

For production, I have a `Dockerfile` which serves a React app using Nginx:

```
# Stage 1

FROM node:15.6.0-alpine3.10 as react-build
WORKDIR /app/client/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2 - the production environment

FROM nginx:1.19.6
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=react-build /app/client/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

While for the backend written in Node / Express, I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:15.6.0-alpine3.10
WORKDIR /app/server/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

These containers are managed with this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  # React Client
  web:
    image: xxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/client:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  # Node Server
  server:
    image: xxx.dkr.ecr.xxx.amazonaws.com/server:latest
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Here the `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
  
  include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**PREMISES**

- On local everything works fine, I run React through `react-scripts` and the backend with `docker-compose` (and so without the React client)
- Both images have been pushed to `AWS ECR`, their content is the equivalent of the `Dockerfile` above
- When fetching the server, endpoints look like `fetch("/users/:id", {..})`
- On `package.json`, I've set `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"`
- Both images have both been tested and are working, both on dev and prod

**PROBLEM**

When hitting an api endpoint from the client, I get a `405 (Not Allowed)`.

That's actually expected, as I'm not really telling the client (Nginx) where to redirect these calls to.

Inspecting the network tab I can see the request is made against `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80` (which represents the client), when it should be redirected to same address but port `8080` instead (where the Express server stands).

On development it works since there's `proxy` set on `package.json`, but that's for development only, so it won't affect production.

**WHAT I TRIED**

- Using `links` on `docker-compose`, not supported from `AWS`
- Using `driver networks` on `docker-compose`, not supported from `AWS`
- Adding `proxy_pass` on `nginx.conf`, but haven't been able to make it working

**CONCLUSIONS**

So premised all this, how can I connect a React build served with Nginx (client) to a Node server when both dockerized and on production?

I believe it should need some configuration on `nginx.conf`, but what I tried didn't land me that far.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Where you run the docker-compose ? In your local machine or on AWS ?

Comment: Mainly on AWS for production - It works if tested locally, but for development I wouldn't use it

Comment: where is your react code that call the backend? are you sure the requests are not https (thus, redirected)

Comment: The react code calling the backend is a simple fetch looking like `fetch("/users", {..})` Can confirm the requests are not on https as the console error `405 (Not Allowed)` contains the url on http - If you are curious about the react code itself, you can find the open source codebase here: https://github.com/ale917k/react-auth-starter

Comment: no need to delete your question even if it's a duplicate. It can be helpful for people searching for the same thing plus it's not a common question so we don't have a lot of them around.

Comment: @ale917k Does it work locally without `proxy` in `package.json`? Does it work with docker service name instead of localhost? `"proxy": "http://server:8080/"`

Comment: @anemyte Can confirm it does not work locally without `proxy` being set up on `package.json`; Same if using `"proxy": "http://server:8080/"` instead of `"http://localhost:8080/"` (I think that's because the frontend is not dockerized locally, so it doesn't know how to reach containers)

Comment: Please help to share your nginx.conf file

Comment: @Ashok, you can see my `nginx.conf` just above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to specify proxy pass directive for your api calls - I would propose to add `/api` in your fetch calls. Than provide upstream using the same name for your backend service as specified in docker-compose.yml. It is important that backend service proceed the web service in docker-compose.yml, otherwise you would get connection error in nginx like this `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend:8080"` You can update your nginx.conf as follows:

```
upstream backend {
  server backend:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
  
  include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Or simply in your case provide a proxy pass to localhost as follows:

```
server {
   listen 80;
      
   location / {
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     index index.html index.htm;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
   }
  
   location /api {
     rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
   }
      
   include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think this is the right one, but for some reason when I try deploying the instances it seems to time out.. https://ibb.co/j5S3ZMk - Any idea why that's the case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you with AWS deployment. But you could try to build everything locally first, to ensure that everything is fine.

Comment: @ale917k I would also try to change service name from "server" to something else. It could probably cause some issues in nginx.conf.

Comment: Good point, done it and here's the outcome: Found out aws was not deploying as the nginx container was failing, returning `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "server:8080" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2` (and I've changed the server name to 'node' instead to avoid possible conflicts as suggested)

Comment: Tried changing upstream `server:8080` to `localhost:8080` to give it a shot and that solves the error, the container now runs (it gets deployed as well), but whenever hitting an endpoint it still doesn't work.. It returns a `502 (Bad Gateway)` and the endpoint request seems to still be made against `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80`

Comment: Error logged when hitting the api: https://ibb.co/x3dxmWQ - `upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream`

Comment: @ale917k I suggest to return everything you had back. The "host not found" error indicates that you are launching your web server before backend. You simply need to change the order of services in your docker-compose file. Put "server" first and "web" second. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Actually, after days of debugging, I've handled to make it work using localhost instead. I think the previous `502` was caused by the db uri not authenticated when on prod (something out of scope for this question); If can help future readers, I've fixed that by referencing the db uri same way using `localhost` instead of `containername`

Answer (score 0):

Sample Docker file, Included the Production build in the docker file

```
FROM node:15.6.0-alpine3.10 as react-build

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install && mkdir /react-frontend && mv ./node_modules ./react-frontend

WORKDIR /app/client/

COPY . .

RUN npm run build



# ------------------------------------------------------
# Production Build
# ------------------------------------------------------
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=builder /react-frontend/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

To add `nginx` as a server to our app we need to create a `nginx.conf` in the project root folder. Below is the sample file

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

Comment: How would this help redirecting frontend calls to the backend? You haven't set any `proxy_pass`, so everything that `nginx.conf` does is serving frontend files